# Is there a way to add slug to home_url on this function?

Tags: permalinks

I have a hard time figuring out how to do the following. I have this function, which broadcast an url from my wordpress posts to my social accounts on Twitter and Facebook, but it shares them with the wrong permalink which have this structure: `www.example.com/?p=2265`, but I need it to show with this permalink structure: `www.example.com/category/postname/`, as this is the permalink structure that I've set (`/%category%/%postname%/`). Is there a way to adjust this to show the permalink structure that I want?

This is the entire function:

```
public function add_broadcasted_id($post_id, $service, $broadcasted_id, $message, $account, Social_Response $response = null) {
    $broadcasted_ids = get_post_meta($post_id, '_social_broadcasted_ids', true);
    if (empty($broadcasted_ids)) {
        $broadcasted_ids = array();
    }

    if (!isset($broadcasted_ids[$service])) {
        $broadcasted_ids[$service] = array();
    }

    if (!isset($broadcasted_ids[$service][$account->id()])) {
        $broadcasted_ids[$service][$account->id()] = array();
    }

    if (!isset($broadcasted_ids[$service][$account->id()][$broadcasted_id])) {
        $urls = array(
            get_permalink($post_id)
        );

        $shortlink = social_get_shortlink($post_id);
        if (!in_array($shortlink, $urls)) {
            $urls[] = $shortlink;
        }

        $home_url = home_url('?p='.$post_id);
        if (!in_array($home_url, $urls)) {
            $urls[] = $home_url;
        }

        $data = array(
            'message' => $message,
            'urls' => $urls
        );
        $data = apply_filters('social_save_broadcasted_ids_data', $data, $account, $service, $post_id, $response);
        $broadcasted_ids[$service][$account->id()][$broadcasted_id] = $data;
        update_post_meta($post_id, '_social_broadcasted_ids', $broadcasted_ids);
    }
}
```

Comment: You could try nuking the portion where it puts the $home_url in the $urls array.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Andrew, but sadly that doesn't work. I changed `!in_array($home_url, $urls)´ to `!in_array($urls)´, but it doesn't do the trick :/.

Comment: Is the function from a plugin or some other larger package?

Comment: Yes, it's from the plugin called Social. I know I should ask or seek for support there, but unfortunately, this question have been done multiple times, and it seems the developer has no answer about it. It's a shame, because it makes the intention rather futile because of this, as it tends to look ugly on the social networks. But I think this function might be the key to solve this issue.